# Error ( Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') even after defining it correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, strapi

I have a custom hook `useFetch` which returns data as a state carrying API data.

`useFetch`:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { fetchDataFromApi } from "./api";

const useFetch = (endpoint) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ data: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    makeApiCall();
  }, [endpoint]);

  const makeApiCall = async () => {
    const res = await fetchDataFromApi(endpoint);
    setData(res);
  };

  return { data };
};

export default useFetch;
```

But when I use the hook it says data is undefined, even though I have defined it as `{data: []}`.
In other places its working well, like here:

```
const details = data?.data[0]?.attributes;

<img
            className="mx-auto"
            src={
              import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_DEV_URL +
              details?.P_img?.data[0]?.attributes?.url
            }
            alt=""
          />
```

and here too:

```
const details = data?.data[0]?.attributes;

<h2 className="text-sm text-gray-600 pb-2 lg:text-base lg:pb-4">
            &#8377;{details?.Price}
          </h2>
          <p className="text-xs text-gray-400 pb-8 lg:text-sm">
            {details?.Desc}
          </p>
```

but does not work here:

`const catId = data.data[0].attributes.categoreies.data[0].attributes.Title;` or here

```
<RelatedProducts
        productId={id}
        categoryId={details.categoreies.data[0].attributes.Title}
      />
```

I wanted to pass the current category id through a prop but it is showing undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

use optional chaining when trying to access deeply nested properties

```
const catId = data?.data[0]?.attributes?.categoreies?.data[0]?.attributes?.Title;
```

check if data is available

```
if (!data || !data.data || !data.data.length) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>; // or null or some placeholder
}
```

Comment: the problem is it is saying its undefined, if i add optional channeling it stops and doesnt execute my data. idk why is it saying that data is undefined